# I think i have a sweeper bot on my account

Tags: transactions, scam, sweeping

I'm having an issue where eth deposited is being swept straight from my wallet.

I haven't used the wallet in quite a while

I recently signed upto to a private sale of tokens.

Sent 0.0205 ETH TO MY METAMASK from coinbase strangly this doesn't appear in my etherscan transactions but the ETH did arrive at my wallet.

I interacted with the smart contract for the token sale sending 0.19 ETH plus a fee of 0.01236.

I had a remaining balance of 0.00546 which was transferred out NOT by me about 26 minutes later

I sent another 0.00443 ETH as a test which was transferred out on the very next block

Reviewing my other transactions there was a transfer out of 0.00158 ETH on October 2nd that I didn't send

If anyone needs to check my wallet address is

0xD2818f5c40Ab169872159CFFa9cE4cD619449a79

Obviously the account is compromised but I have a few questions

How come the coinbase in transactions isn't showing on etherscan but still appeared in my account and I was able to send the funds to the smart contract and why wasn't it swept?

Is there anyway the team of the project I invested into can send the tokens to an alternative addrwss as they haven't been distributed yet or is this automated by the contract?

I also have another token in that wallet sat in a staking contract that I can't access without adding ETH is this lost or are there ways to recover?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How come the coinbase transaction does not appear on etherscan?

Coinbase is sending you the ETH from a smart contract. Because of that, the ETH transfer appears under the "Internal Transactions" tab on etherscan. It's there.

### Why wasn't it sweeped?

Don't know. Maybe the sweeper bot does not monitor internal transactions...

### Can I change the address to receive the tokens?

The contract that you sent ETH to is not an ERC20 token contract. It simply stores the amount of tokens that you purchased based on the address that sent the ETH, but it does not allow transfers or anything like that. The actual ERC20 tokens must be sent from another smart contract in the future. You may ask the team to change the address they send it to when (and if) they send the actual ERC20 tokens later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have sorted my tokens with the team of the project so thats one problem solved. I guess next I need to send a small amount of ethereum to the wallet from coinbase an see if it gets swept just enough for the fees to unstake and claim rewards then left it sweep the small left overs then make another deposit from coinbase to get the tokens out 